# How to open multiple .RDATA and save one of there names as data.frame

Tags: r, rdata

I have a multiple .RData files and I need to save one of their objects as a data frame. For instance, I have 5 Rdata file in certain folder and I see it like this,

```
files <- list.files(path="/home/user/data/bumphunter", pattern="*.RData", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
```

which shows me,

```
files
[1] "/home/R1/Results.alt_ID.RData" 
[2] "/home/R1/Results.alt.RData"    
[3] "/home/R1/Results.alt_REL.RData"
[4] /home/R1/Results.DU_ID.RData"   
[5] "/home/R1/Results.DU.RData"      
[6] "/home/R1/Results.DU_REL.RData"  
[7] "/home/R1/Results.P_ID.RData"   
[8] "/home/R1/Results.P.RData"      
[9] "/home/R1/Results.P_REL.RData"
```

And each RData has objects with names for example

```
names(Results.alt_ID.RData)
```

And I need the object named table to be saved as a new seperate data frame for each Rdata

I need the object table saved as a dataframe from each of these .Rdata files. Is there a way I could do it within a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My list of file names are pretty simple, "mt.Rdata" and "mt1.Rdata"

The code I have for having dataframes for every file is

```
files <- list.files(getwd())


for(i in files){
    print(i)
    df <- load(i)
    assign(gsub("\\..*","", i), df ) #extracts the string before period
    rm(df)
    }
```

Let me know if this is what your are looking for.

Comment: Do you have an example code because I tried a lot to figure out how could I get there, like this, for example, table<-function(files)
       {
 load(files,ex<-new.env())
        
 tab=ex$Results[1]$table
       }

Comment: You want to append or separate dfs?

Comment: I wanted to save it as seperate data frames .I need the object table from each Rdata

Comment: Yes  Thank you , But i am wondering how can I select the object here , or where do I select it in the loop ?

Comment: one way would be to check for the classes of the object and in the Rdata file once loaded. Then assign that object to the df, so instead of having 'df' as the dataframe, first load the file and then use df<- ... to have your dataframe with the identified object.